# Only allow letters, numbers, underscores or hyphens django

Tags: django

I have a form that allows a user to register for my app using the UserModel . I'm trying to only allow  letters, numbers, underscores or hyphens in the username . I'm been trying to use validate_slug¶ but I don't understand how to use it probably to verify if the input submitted is only letters, numbers, underscores or hyphens otherwise raise an error.

Can someone please help me

```
class UserRegistration(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))


        def clean_username(self):
            username = self.cleaned_data['username']

                if "@" in username:
                    raise forms.ValidationError("Sorry , you cannot use the symbol @")
                return username
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex match, and instead of validating every possiblity, validate only against allowed characters:

```
import re
if not re.match(r'^[A-Za-z0-9_-]+$', username):
    raise forms.ValidationError("Sorry , you can only have alphanumeric, _ or - in username")
```